# Ruby: How do you use .uniq! on an array to look for duplicates based on a regex .scan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a hard time grasping the .uniq! method. I'm trying to remove duplicate ips alerts in my view.

If I use the code in `Original Code:` I receive all alerts from the IPS in my `Index View:`.
This will show all alerts, for example; I will receive 500 alerts that can be condensed down to 1 alert based on the signature ID (sid), Source IP (ip_src), and Destination IP (ip_dst). If I just append .uniq! (if thats even how it should be used) I don't get any different results, I assume it does not work because the timestamps and source ports are not the same, so it already is unique. Here are two sample messages that should be one instead of two.

`04/04-16:13:47.451062 [**] [1:10000001:1] <dna0:dna1> drop - WP-Admin attempt [**] [Classification: Web Application Attack] [Priority: 1] {TCP} 10.17.21.37:55749 -> 173.239.96.163:80`

`04/04-16:13:28.474894 [**] [1:10000001:1] <dna0:dna1> drop - WP-Admin attempt [**] [Classification: Web Application Attack] [Priority: 1] {TCP} 10.17.21.37:55707 -> 173.239.96.163:80`

I would like to use the signature ID (sid), Source IP (ip_src), and Destination IP (ip_dst) of every message, and remove the duplicates.

I used the `.scan` method to find the signature ID, source IP, and destination IP. They are buit as `sid, ip_src, ip_dst`. I'm stuck on the line `@filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail).uniq!` and do not really know how I need to use the information in `sid, ip_src, ip_dst` to make `@filtered_snort_detail_query` pass unique alerts to my view.

Index View:

```
<% if @filtered_snort_detail_query.count > 0 %>
  <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Tag Info</th>
        <th>Message</th>
      </tr>
      <% @filtered_snort_detail_query.each do |d|
        text_msg = d['_source']['message']
        if d['_source']['message'].nil?
        end
      %>
          <tr>
            <td class='timestamp'><%= d['_source']['@timestamp'].to_time %></td>
            <td class='tags'><%= d['_source']['tags'] %></td>
            <td class='message'><%= text_msg %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>

    </table>
<% else %>
    <div> No Results Returned. </div>
<% end %>
```

Original Code:

```
if @es_snort_detail_query.count > 0
      @filtered_snort_detail_query = Array.new
      @es_snort_detail_query.each do |ips_detail|
        next if ips_detail['_source']['type'] != 'snort-ips'
        next if ips_detail['_source']['@timestamp'] < @ts
        @filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail)
      end
 end
```

Modified Code:

```
    if @es_snort_detail_query.count > 0
      sid = Array.new
      ip_src = Array.new
      ip_dst = Array.new
      @filtered_snort_detail_query = Array.new
      @es_snort_detail_query.each do |ips_detail|
        next if ips_detail['_source']['type'] != 'snort-ips'
        next if ips_detail['_source']['@timestamp'] < @ts
        if ips_detail['_source']['message'].nil?
          text_msg = ips_detail['_source']['message']
        else
          text_msg = ips_detail['_source']['message']
        end
        unless text_msg.nil?
          sid_data = text_msg.scan(/\[\d+:\d+:\d+\]/)
          src_ip_data = text_msg.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
          dst_ip_data = text_msg.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
          sid.push(sid_data[0]) unless sid_data[0].nil?
          ip_src.push(src_ip_data[0]) unless src_ip_data[0].nil?
          ip_dst.push(dst_ip_data[1]) unless dst_ip_data[1].nil?

          @filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail).uniq!
          #[{:unique_ids => sid}, {:unique_ids => ip_src}, {:unique_ids => ip_dst}]
        end
      end
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a block to [`uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) to tell it how you want to dedup your array:

```
@filtered_snort_detail_query = @es_snort_detail_query.reject do |ips_detail|
  ips_detail['_source']['type'] != 'snort-ips' || ips_detail['_source']['@timestamp'] < @ts
end.uniq do |ips_detail|
  if ips_detail['_source']['message'].nil?
    text_msg = ips_detail['_source']['message']
  else
    text_msg = ips_detail['_source']['message']
  end
  unless text_msg.nil?
    sid_data = text_msg.scan(/\[\d+:\d+:\d+\]/)
    src_ip_data = text_msg.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
    dst_ip_data = text_msg.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
    [sid_data, src_ip_data, dst_ip_data]
  end
end
```